# Is the design tag still useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

The description of the [design](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) tag seems to focus on game design, and I think 90% of the questions in it could/should be retagged game-design. Is this tag doing anything for us besides splitting up game design questions into two tags?

Answer (score 13):

[design](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) seems indeed to be (mostly) used as a synonym of [game-design](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design).

Both tags cover asking practical game design questions ("I'm making a game and stuck on this part") and cover asking why certain design decisions were made ("Game X did this thing, why did they do that?").

The exception is a small number of [design](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) questions that are about design of other things, which I've identified below. I've dropped the design tag from these or replaced it with a specific design tag (like [adventure-writing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure-writing)).

If we don't create a synonym, we should definitely be retagging most of these [design](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) questions to [game-design](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design).

---

Questions where I've dropped or replaced the [design](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) tag:

- [What to do in the Shadowfell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/595/what-to-do-in-the-shadowfell)
- [Are there advantages to descending AC?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56138/are-there-advantages-to-descending-ac) (also had [game-design](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design))
- [Show off your Character Sheet Designs](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37806/show-off-your-character-sheet-designs)
- [What do I consider when populating D&D 4E Dungeons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/41170/what-do-i-consider-when-populating-dd-4e-dungeons)
- [Has anyone released Castle of the Mad Archmage upper levels?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1721/has-anyone-released-castle-of-the-mad-archmage-upper-levels)
- [How can I turn the Kobold Hall delve into a full-fledged Adventure?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6059/how-can-i-turn-the-kobold-hall-delve-into-a-full-fledged-adventure) [closed]
- [Help Identify a Medieval City](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/help-identify-a-medieval-city) [closed]
- [Are there any free tools for designing encounters or traps?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4941/are-there-any-free-tools-for-designing-encounters-or-traps) [closed]

I'm pretty sure the rest of the [design](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) questions are just [game-design](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design) questions.

Comment: Based on the the uncontroversial support for this answer and the lack of counterproposals, [[tag:design]] has been merged into [[tag:game-design]]. Thanks for the prepwork that made it a clean merge!